# How can I retrieve a cell containing a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5

**I am (unfortunately) updating a DotNetNuke 5 desktop module**

I have a button handler:

```
protected void ButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    TableCell tblCell = button.Parent;
}
```

I have also tried the above using NamingContainer - but both options are throwing this error at me:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'
```

How can I retrieve the table cell that the button lives in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast it :

```
TableCell tblCell = (TableCell)button.Parent;
```